# ggplot help editing and the order of facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good afternoon,

I have completed a bar graph using ggplot using the following code:

```
pd = position_dodge(0.92) ggplot(data=SummaryStats, aes(x=ProbeState, y=GazeCueTarget.RT, fill=CueType)) +

geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 

facet_grid(.~RecallType,space = "free", scale="free_x") + 

geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=GazeCueTarget.RT-se, ymax=GazeCueTarget.RT+se), width=.1, position=pd) +

geom_text(aes(label = GazeCueTarget.RT), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = "dodge")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

This comes from the following data with a bar for each condition considering reaction time

[image]

My variables are `ProbeState` (digits/positions), `RecallType` (forwards/backwards/control), and `CueType` (cued/uncued).

However there are a couple of issues I would like help with regarding ggplot. The first and most obvious is that the bar values are not well done. They need reduced down to a couple of decimal places only. I have toyed around with adding round(digits = 2) into my code but with no luck. If these values can be centred close to the top of the bar and made a little bigger that would be ideal.

The second issue is that I am not entirely sure how to rearrange the order of the facet grid so that it displays c(“forwards, backwards, control) in that order from left to right. The default looks to set to alphabetical order and after looking I am still not sure on how to adjust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geom_text(aes(label = round(GazeCueTarget.RT,2)), size = 3, vjust = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
```

Should take care of the rounding and the position aspect, and 'width' should control how far apart they are.

```
SummaryStats$RecallType <- factor(SummaryStats$RecallType, levels = c('forwards','backwards','control'), ordered = T)
```

Should be run before making the plot to control the order of the facet grid.

Comment: Thank you for your help Balter. The facet grid order solution was perfect! I had to tinker with the first line of code you put in your answer. For whatever reason it wasn't quite working. The console kept appearing with +. I updated it and got the desired result using the following  geom_text(aes(label = format(SummaryStats$GazeCueTarget.RT, digits = 2)), size = 4, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))

Thanks again.

Comment: Oh yep.  I missed a ')' to close the 'aes' bracket.  Fixed.  You're welcome :)